# Swift 2.0: sort instead of sorted function

Tags: swift, sorting

I have (in swift 1) this line of code:

```
keys = sorted(namesDict!.allKeys as! [String])
```

but function sorted is not supported anymore (Swift 2.0).
What can i write to have keys sorted?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer seems to be in the question's title already.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your own question. The `sort` function returns a sorted array, you can store it in a variable.

```
let dict = ["b":1, "a":2, "c":3]
let sortedKeys = dict.keys.sort() //returns ["a", "b", "c"]
```